# Laravel getDirty() double and int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following to create and log history in my app:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    self::updating(function($item)
    {
        $changes = array();

        foreach ($item->getDirty() as $key => $value) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'supplierId':
                    $supplier1 = Supplier::find($item->original[$key]);
                    $supplier2 = Supplier::find($value);
                    $changes[] = 'Changed supplier fee from ' . $supplier1->name . ' to ' . $supplier2->name;
                    break;
                case 'typeId':
                    $from = EnquiriesBuyingFeesTypes::find($item->original[$key]);
                    $to = EnquiriesBuyingFeesTypes::find($value);
                    $changes[] = 'Changed fee type from ' . $from['charge'] . ' to ' . $to['charge'];
                    break;
                case 'currencyId':
                    $from = Currency::find($item->original[$key])->symbol;
                    $to = Currency::find($value)->symbol;
                    $changes[] = 'Changed fee currency from ' . $from . ' to ' . $to;
                    break;
                case 'net':
                    $changes[] = 'Changed fee net from ' . $item->original[$key] . ' to ' . $value;
                    break;
                default:
                    $changes[] = 'Changed fee ' . $key . ' from ' . $item->original[$key] . ' to ' . $value;
                    break;
            }
        }

        foreach ($changes as $change) {
            Enquiry\History::create(array(
                'enquiryId' => $item->enquiryId,
                'details' => $change
            ));
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, when any field is changed it always thinks that 'net' has changed. An example result is 'Changed fee net from 3.00 to 3'

How can I make the getDirty() function to treat any integer for net as a decimal, so 3.00 compared to 3.00 will not be recorded as a change?

Answer (score 0):

Try the new Eloquent casts, this might solve your problem. http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#attribute-casting

```
class Model extends Eloquent {

    protected $casts = [
        'net' => 'double',
    ]

}
```

So by doing the above, Eloquent will cast the net attribute as a double, so you'll receive a double every time you ask for it, even if it is 3.00

Comment: Thanks, but it had no effect :(